# Django Filename Generation Issue

Tags: django, caching, video, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Django based media server that accepts a variety of video formats for upload. While uploading a large .wmv file, I noticed some strange behavior. The first time I uploaded the video, it took almost five minutes to convert and upload. Thereafter, some sort of caching occurred, and the video would merely point to the one I had previously uploaded. I don't understand why this is happening. When a video is uploaded, the file name extension is checked for conversion purposes, and then an ffmpeg command is executed to carry out the conversion. This is all run asynchronously, using django-celery with RabbitMQ as the message broker. I don't see any reason why the ffmpeg conversion command would not execute again. Here is my code for the celery task that handles the upload. (This was my initial reasoning, look at the EDIT for the correct error diagnosis)

```
@celery.task
def handleFileUploadAsync(update, m, file_type, video_types):
    filename = m.file.name.replace(' ', '\\ ')
    if video_types[file_type] == 'wmv':
        os.system(
            "ffmpeg -i " + MEDIA_ROOT + filename + " -strict experimental -vcodec libx264    -profile:v baseline " + MEDIA_ROOT + filename.replace(video_types[file_type],'mp4')
    )
        m.file.name = m.file.name.replace(video_types[file_type], 'mp4')
        m.save() 
        os.remove(m.file.path.replace('mp4', 'wmv'))
    elif file_type in video_types.keys():
        os.system(
         "ffmpeg -i " + MEDIA_ROOT + filename + " -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -s 672x576 " + MEDIA_ROOT + filename.replace(video_types[file_type],'mp4')
        )
        m.file.name = m.file.name.replace(video_types[file_type], 'mp4')
        m.save()
        if video_types[file_type] != 'mp4':
            os.remove(m.file.path.replace('mp4', video_types[file_type]))
```

EDIT:

Here's the problem. When I convert videos, I only want the converted .mp4 file, not the original upload. Django generates filenames from the file upload field, automatically appending numbers to the end of existing files (i.e. test.mp4, test_1.mp4, test_2.mp4, etc.). However, when I upload a video like test.wmv, there will be no file named test.wmv after the conversion is complete (I delete the non-converted file). Is there any way I can modify Django method that generates these filenames??

Answer (score 0):

Use [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) when declaring the FileField. Maybe use the object's primary key as the filename?